# ListFragment shows "Empty List" when it most definitely is not

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I'm trying to set an adapter to a ListFragment, but no matter what I do it always appears as an "Empty List". I'm instantiating studentList just before setting the adapter. There must be something very simple that I'm missing. How can I write this so that my code displays the given studentList?

Main Screen.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/empty_list"
            style="@style/font_large"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainScreenFrag.java

```
public class MainScreenFrag extends ListFragment {

    public final static String TITLE = "Student List";
    public final static String TAG = "MainScreenFrag";

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] studentList =  {"me", "you", "everybody", "nobody","some people", "most people", "just me", "ok you too"};

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                studentList));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen, container, false);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling

```
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
```

in your `onViewCreated`

Give that a try

Answer (score -1):

Its mostly because you have not given an id for your list Adapter.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, studentList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

This should work, though the method seems redundant.

Comment: ListFragment automatically looks for a ListView with id/list; you don't need to set it explicitly.

Comment: No harm trying using an id. It worked many times for me. Eclipse gives such absurd responses.

Comment: What I have compiles without errors or warning. Unfortunately, it doesn't display my list! It will however display the text "Empty List"

Comment: It will work - I'm saying it's redundant. The ListFragment does that exact same lookup for you, and when you call setAdapter, it delegates it to that ListView.